# Need a very simple example for parsing and writing XML docs in C or in C++

Tags: c++, c, xml

I work on a C project and need to implement some interactions with XML files.

I need a **very simple** example for parsing and for writing an XML file.

I really prefer a small library (like one **.h** file and one **.c** file), and not a library that requires installation

I'll be very glad if someone can show me:

- how to parse the data in the following example
- how to generate the data in the following example

XML data:

```
<root>
    <source name = 'source1' isReadOnly = 'false'>
        <view name = 'view1' />
        <view name = 'view2' />
    </source>
    <source name = 'source2' isReadOnly = 'true'>
        <view name = 'view1' />
        <view name = 'view2' />
    </source>
</root>
```

Comment: Boost Property Tree can be used to parse XML. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/property_tree.html - I think it is header-only.

Comment: _"I really prefer a small library (like one .h file and one .c file)"_ You may have a big misconception here. Parsing XML correctly is a much more complex task, that one would reasonably solve in a single module.

Comment: use pugixml parser. It simple and easy! http://cdn.rawgit.com/zeux/pugixml/v1.4/docs/quickstart.html

Comment: Why shy away from using larger and well established libraries that have proven to do what they are supposed to do ? It may destroy the myth of the solitary genius but >50% of the work is using and understanding the work of others. If however your mission is explicitly to design a minimalistic XML-Parser from scratch, you might want to inform yourself about regular expression parsing with boost which however is also a quite heav lib...

Comment: I want a well established "standard" library, but `libxml` and `expat` require a lot of prework before you can start using it

Comment: @SomethingSomething Agreed but XML Parsing/Generation is something you are likely to encounter lots and lots of times and it really pays of to establish a feature rich library for you. This of course contradicts the basic fact that things always have to be finished yesterday.

Comment: @Oncaphillis _"It may destroy the myth of the solitary genius"_ - The solitary genius leverages all suitable tools available and knows working harder than necessary is a fools endeavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find pugixml to be very easy to use. It comes as a small source file that you can compile in to your project.

**Example *C++03*:**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "pugixml.hpp"

int main()
{
    using namespace pugi;

    // Load XML file from fstream

    std::ifstream xml_file("test.xml");

    if(!xml_file)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: opening XML file: " << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    xml_document doc;

    xml_parse_result res = doc.load(xml_file);

    if(!res)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << res.description() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // get all children of <root><source>

    xml_object_range<xml_named_node_iterator> sources =
        doc.child("root").children("source");

    // Iterate through <root><source> children

    xml_named_node_iterator s;
    for(s = sources.begin(); s != sources.end(); ++s)
    {
        // get all children named <root><source><view>

        xml_object_range<xml_named_node_iterator> views =
            s->children("view");

        // Iterate through <root><source><view> children

        xml_named_node_iterator v;
        for(v = views.begin(); v != views.end(); ++v)
            std::cout << v->attribute("name").value() << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Example *C++11*:**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "pugixml.hpp"

int main()
{
    using namespace pugi;

    std::ifstream xml_file("test.xml");

    if(!xml_file)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: opening XML file: " << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    xml_document doc;

    xml_parse_result res = doc.load(xml_file);

    if(!res)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << res.description() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    auto sources = doc.child("root").children("source");

    for(auto&& s: sources)
    {
        auto views = s.children("view");

        for(auto&& v: views)
            std::cout << v.attribute("name").value() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example is just great! Worked to me with very little effort

Answer (score 1):

There are many articles regarding this on internet. Assuming you are on windows find below example for your reference:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Car>
    <Wheels>
        <Wheel1>FL</Wheel1>
        <Wheel2>FR</Wheel2>
        <Wheel3>RL</Wheel3>
        <Wheel4>RR</Wheel4>
    </Wheels>
</Car>
```

Below is the code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#import <msxml6.dll> rename_namespace(_T("MSXML"))

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        try
        {
            MSXML::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr xmlDoc;
            hr = xmlDoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML::DOMDocument60), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
            // TODO: if (FAILED(hr))...

            if (xmlDoc->load(_T("input.xml")) != VARIANT_TRUE)
            {
                printf("Unable to load input.xml\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("XML was successfully loaded\n");

                xmlDoc->setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
                MSXML::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr wheels = xmlDoc->selectNodes("/Car/Wheels/*");
                printf("Car has %u wheels\n", wheels->Getlength());

                MSXML::IXMLDOMNodePtr node;
                node = xmlDoc->createNode(MSXML::NODE_ELEMENT, _T("Engine"), _T(""));
                node->text = _T("Engine 1.0");
                xmlDoc->documentElement->appendChild(node);
                hr = xmlDoc->save(_T("output.xml"));
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    printf("output.xml successfully saved\n");
            }
        }
        catch (_com_error &e)
        {
            printf("ERROR: %ws\n", e.ErrorMessage());
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can also consult following links:-

http://codeproject.com/Articles/587488/Streaming-XML-parser-in-Cplusplus

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765540(v=vs.85).aspx

Contrary to this if you're on linux platform then go for TinyXml:-

http://grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/

Comment: I need linux. I'll take a look at the tinyXML. Thanks!